# How to change Layout background dynamically in Android?

Tags: android, xml, json, layout, imageurl

I have parsed `JSON` at the time of Splash screen, in which image url is parsed for **background image for login screen**. Here is sample `XML`code for login screen:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/loginLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_bg"  <!-- I want to change this background dynamically. --> 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".activity.LoginActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/mainScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

 <!-- .... Here is edit text for login inputs and buttuns for singnup and login. -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

In above i have placed static image in the background of `RelativeLayout` but i want to make backgroud as changeble according to image url.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert url image to bitmap then bitmap image to Drawable  and set it RelativeLayout.

First convert url image to bitmap, see the sample code.

```
Bitmap myImage = getBitmapFromURL("http://looksok.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/me.jpg");
```

Take RelativeLayout reference

```
RelativeLayout rLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
```

BitmapDrawable(obj) convert Bitmap object into drawable object.

```
Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(myImage);
rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

Url image to bitmap convertion method

```
 public Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is throwing exception at connection.connect();

Comment: 08-06 09:55:57.635: W/System.err(19973): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @user3751280 You need to use `AsyncTask`

Comment: and another one is : 08-06 09:55:57.655: W/System.err(19973): java.io.IOException
08-06 09:55:57.656: W/System.err(19973):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:87)
08-06 09:55:57.656: W/System.err(19973):  at np.com.autolife.activity.LoginActivity.getBitmapFromURL(LoginActivity.java:275)

Comment: @user3751280 check my answer, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

1. Download Latest AndroidQuery jar from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/downloads/list):
2. Put this jar to your libs folder and right click on jar and Build Path -> Add to bulid path.
3. How to use see this example:

   AQuery androidQuery = new AQuery(this);

   ```
   androidQuery.ajax(url.trim(), Bitmap.class, 0, new AjaxCallback<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void callback(String url, Bitmap object, AjaxStatus status) {
            super.callback(url, object, status);
            yourRelativeLayout.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(object));
        }
   });
   ```

Comment: Where is a link to download jar file?

Comment: Please check now i have added.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

Call the AsyncTask like this

```
 new GetImageFromServer().execute(strUrl);  // strUrl is your URL
```

Here is the AsyncTask class

```
public class GetImageFromServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
    {


        private Bitmap image;

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params){
            try{

                URL urli = new URL(params[0].trim());
                URLConnection ucon = urli.openConnection();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;


                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ucon.getInputStream(),null,options);

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return image;  //<<< return Bitmap
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result){ 

             RelativeLayout relative = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.loginLayout);
             Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(result);
             relative.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);

            }


    }
```